# GetAsyncKeyState not detecting mouse input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Writing a simple C++ program and using GetAsyncKeyState to trigger different functions. When using buttons (VK_MENU) for example, everything works fine. But when I use VK_LBUTTON, only like 1/100 presses are detected.

My detector line is simply

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) { do stuff; }
```

Can anyone suggest why this happens?

Comment: Usual reminder about `GetAsyncKeyState`: it's not a proper method to obtain user input, you risk losing events and isn't properly synchronized with the thread's input queue. Use the regular mouse/keyboard input messages.

Comment: Why? I need a function that can run in the background as my window isn't focused. When used properly GetAsyncKeyState has worked for me everytime

Comment: If you need a (global) hotkey, use the right tool for the job: [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

I resolved the issue. It was due to another bug further down my code. The actual GetAsyncKeyState was executing properly.

Comment: This doesn't really provide a useful answer to the question. Best to remove both question and answer.